# Tally up results from a grep search?

Tags: bash

Say I have a list such as this:

```
8
382.34.6
sally
sally
8
923
183.3.3
183.3.3
183.3.3
8
```

And I want to tally up the number of times each unique value repeats and get output like this:

```
8 3
382.34.6 1
sally 2
923 1
183.3.3 3
```

What command would I need to run to do this?  If it makes a difference, the list is coming from a `grep` search.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
sort file | uniq -c | awk '{print $2,$1}'
```

Output:

```
183.3.3 3
382.34.6 1
8 3
923 1
sally 2
```

Comment: As I saw later, waltinator had a very similar idea.

Comment: You can accept @Cyrus's post as the answer if this indeed helped you.

Comment: If you prefer to have the counts separated by TAB instead of space (useful if the lines themselves contain space characters), you can use sort file | uniq -c | sed "s%^ *\([0-9][0-9]*\) %\1\t%g"|awk -F$'\t' {'print $2"\t"$1'}

Answer (score 2):

You could feed the list through `| sort | uniq -c | sort -n`, Like this:

```
echo -e "8\n382.34.6\nsally\nsally\n8\n923\n183.3.3\n183.3.3\n183.3.3\n8" | \
sort | uniq -c | sort -n
      1 382.34.6
      1 923
      2 sally
      3 183.3.3
      3 8
```

If you want the counts after the values, you could append `| awk '{print $2,$1}'`

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `awk` as follows: create an associative array, keyed by the item to be counted, and increment it each time the same item is read; at the end of input, iterate over the array and print the keys and counts:

```
your grep command | awk '{a[$0]++;next;}; END{for (i in a) print i,a[i];}'
```

A possible advantage is that you may be able to do the pattern matching directly in `awk`, doing away with `grep` altogether i.e.

```
awk '/your regex/{a[$0]++;next;}; END{for (i in a) print i,a[i];}'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
stuff=(apple,boat,chicken)
for (i=0; i<${#stuff}; i=i+1); do
echo INPUT | grep ${stuff[i]} | wc
done
```

**INPUT** meaning the text to search. Also fill in the array with your words.

Comment: -1, sorry but I won't go through all the problems here. It just doesn't work, starting from the fact that you need to enclose a C-style for loop in double parenthesis. Also I'm no bash parameter expansion expert, but your script runs way more than 3 times, and it doesn't output anything but grep errors. Indeed I changed INPUT to "apple test test chicken" while testing. Please revise it, drop me a comment once done and I'll remove my downvote